# Appending jsonobject to an existing jsonobject

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having a problem with Json file reading and writing. I want to append something into a json file but it doesn't work properly: it just put in a new jsonobject without the '**,**' to divide it from the previous one. I searched everywhere, on every site, but nothing that gave me an input on how to do it properly.

For example, I have a json file like this:

```
{
    "Example":{
        "Ok":"Ok1",
        "Nice":"Nice1",
        "Hi":"Hi1",
        "Hello":"Hello1",
        "Right":"Right1",
        "Wow":"Wow1"
    }
}
```

And I want to make it appear like this:

```
{
    "Example":{
        "Ok":"Ok1",
        "Nice":"Nice1",
        "Hi":"Hi1",
        "Hello":"Hello1",
        "Right":"Right1",
        "Wow":"Wow1"
    },
    "Example1":{
        "Ok":"Ok2",
        "Nice":"Nice2",
        "Hi":"Hi2",
        "Hello":"Hello2",
        "Right":"Right2",
        "Wow":"Wow2"
    }
}
```

So, I tried using this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonObject dati = new JsonObject();
dati.addProperty("Cognome", StringUtils.capitalize((fields[0].getText())));
dati.addProperty("Nome", StringUtils.capitalize((fields[1].getText())));
dati.addProperty("Sesso", lblSesso.getText());
dati.addProperty("Luogo di nascita", StringUtils.capitalize((fields[2].getText())));
dati.addProperty("Provincia", lblProvincia.getText());
dati.addProperty("Data di nascita", fieldDDN.getText());
jsonObject.add(codfis, dati);
String json = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CodFisCalcolati.json"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("CodFisCalcolati.json", true))) {
    String jsonString = gson.fromJson(br, JsonElement.class).toString();
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject.add(codfis, dati);
    String resultingJson = gson.toJson(jelement);
    bw.write(resultingJson);
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

But when I use it, it give me this output :

```
{
    "Example":{
        "Ok":"Ok1",
        "Nice":"Nice1",
        "Hi":"Hi1",
        "Hello":"Hello1",
        "Right":"Right1",
        "Wow":"Wow1"
    }
}{
    "Example":{
        "Ok":"Ok1",
        "Nice":"Nice1",
        "Hi":"Hi1",
        "Hello":"Hello1",
        "Right":"Right1",
        "Wow":"Wow1"
    },
    "Example1":{
        "Ok":"Ok2",
        "Nice":"Nice2",
        "Hi":"Hi2",
        "Hello":"Hello2",
        "Right":"Right2",
        "Wow":"Wow2"
    }
}
```

That's output, you see, it'wrong and i don't know how to make the code to give me a different output.

I'm using Gson 2.8.5 and I would rather not change to another library.

Comment: what those addProperty ? if you are just want to add another example ?

Comment: The program should : read from json file, take the jsonobject and append another one to it. The other one i mean, is **dati**

Comment: Gson is really good for POJO. May be it could be better to create some Java classes reflecting you data structure. Deserialize it form json stream using gson like gson.fromJson(jsonString, classOfT); then do what you want right on Java classes and at finally serialize this class back to json? This additional abstraction level could help you to avoid the problems you have.

Comment: Can you explain to me how should I use pojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the question but now the answer to your new question is you use the same file to read and write. That's why you add the data inside ot the file. Change the name of the file that you write and see if you have problems

Comment: I already thought about that before, but I need to use the same file to read and write.

Comment: Try to put on the FileWriter constructor false as second argument. This way you will not append to the file but overwrite

Comment: Just to be clear  I delete one my comment. My comment was first to read the file and after that delete it. After delete create again the new file with the same name and with the new content content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "br" is not null.

According to the specification of the method fromJson it returns:
an object of type T from the string. Returns null if json is null.

If this is the case than you call on the null toString() method and you get null pointer exception

Comment: Yes I already done it, but the problem persists. I have done it with a simple **if (br != null)** is it right?

Comment: Try to make from br StringBuilder object. After that try JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); and use this json on the place of the br.

Comment: **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null** I don't know why it is null... I have done what you said and it should work...

Comment: Check the other way I did.

Comment: I think your example to work you need to have json in the file from which you read. Can you check the path to the file and also the file not to be empty?

Comment: I tried it as you said, the file exist and isn't empty. i already use it in another part of the code and it works fine.